# What would be the consequences if all _infinite_ NP-complete languages are p-isomorphic?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-complete, p-vs-np

The famous [Isomorphism Conjecture of Berman and Hartmanis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berman%E2%80%93Hartmanis_conjecture) says that all $NP$-complete languages are polynomial time isomorphic ($p$-isomorphic) to each other. It has been an early attempt (published in 1977) to prove $P\neq NP$. It is still open, and if true, it indeed implies $P\neq NP$.

However, the proof of this  implication is essentially trivial: it is proved by referring to the fact that if $P=NP$, then there are finite $NP$-complete languages, which clearly contradicts to the Isomorphism Conjecture, since a finite language cannot be $p$-isomorphic to SAT.

While the above proof is technically correct, I find it somehow disturbing that to prove the implication one needs a finite  $NP$-complete language.

**Question:** Let us consider a weaker version of the conjecture, stating only that all ***infinite*** $NP$-complete languages are $p$-isomorphic. Would this still imply $P\neq NP$? Is anything known about this weaker version of the conjecture?

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berman%E2%80%93Hartmanis_conjecture#Implications) on the conjecture outlines an argument that uses sparsity in lieu of finiteness, but is otherwise essentially the same. Perhaps weaken the conjecture further, to state only that sufficiently dense $\mathsf{NP}$-complete languages are isomorphic? "Sufficiently dense" in this case means that density/sparsity considerations don't eliminate an isomorphism with SAT.

Comment: Perhaps this works: if $P=NP$ then $A = \{2 \uparrow \uparrow n \}$ (towers of 2)  is NPC (just solve the NP problem using the polynomial time algorithm and map to $1 \notin A$ or $2 \in A$ ) but $A$ cannot be p-isomorphic to SAT. So also the weaker conjecture implies $P \neq NP$

Comment: @AndrewMorgan : ​ (I don't know if "density/sparsity" means you already realize this, but) $\hspace{.95 in}$ One would need to require density of the complement too. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Yes, it indeed seems that the "right" version of the weaker conjecture is this: all NP-complete languages with exponential density and co-density are p-isomorphic. (This density requirement means that there is a constant $c>0$, such that both the language and its complement contains $\geq 2^{cn}$ $n$-bit strings for every $n$.)

Comment: That's much stronger than should be necessary: ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ "≥ 2^(n^c) ​ (<n)-bit strings for all sufficiently large n" ​ ​ ​ should be enough. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: It's enough to have two exp. dense and co-dense sets in P that aren't p-isomorphic. Here's a thought: take two non-isomorphic exp. dense sets L,L' in P (shouldn't be too hard to find). Consider $L_1 = L \oplus \overline{L} = \{(0,x) : x \in L\} \cup \{(1,y) : y \notin L\}$ and $L_2 = L \oplus \overline{L}'$. Both $L_1,L_2$ are now exp. dense *and* co-dense, and in P. I don't immediately see how to show that they aren't isomorphic, but it seems like one might be able to get that with a little extra work/diagonalization. If I have time I'll try to work it out...